# Does the Deberta transformer model allow you to output all hidden states?

Tags: python, pytorch, roberta-language-model

I have a custom Deberta model class for a downstream regression task. I have implemented almost the exact same model, except with a pre-trained Roberta model and it works fine. When I switch the the Deberta model I keep getting errors with the hidden state outputs.

```
_pretrained_model = 'deberta-base'

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(_pretrained_model)
config.update({'output_hidden_states':True})
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(_pretrained_model, config=config)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(_pretrained_model)

class DebertaCustomModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained_model_name):
        super(DebertaCustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.deberta = DebertaModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(768, 256)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(256, 2)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):

        outputs = self.deberta(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        all_hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states
        print(all_hidden_states)
```

When I print all_hidden_states it returns None. Does Deberta not allow you to return all all_hidden_states like Roberta does?